# Javascript forEach loop order of operations and execution

Tags: javascript, performance, function, foreach

This is probably such a beginner question but I have a concern about how my global object will be updated.  I'll show what I'm doing and then talk about my concern.

```
(function() {
    var obj = {};
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            //do whatever with the mutation
            //update the obj variable
        });
    });
    observer.observe(target, config);
})();
```

My concern is when the mutations will be coming in back to back to back rapidly, am I guaranteed that the first mutations will finish their process before proceeding to the next batch?  I THINK I understand how closures work but I don't think that's what I need here.  I was thinking about passing each batch of mutations to a function, maybe creating a queue and processing that way...is that a better way to ensure that everything will get processed in order which it came in?  Also creating some kind of callback when each mutation process will be completed, then moving on to the next?  Or does the `forEach` loop handle that for me?

Also while processing these mutations, I think I'm blocking the thread since everything is done synchronously, am I correct?  Should I use a IIFE around each mutation and use `setTimeout()` to make it asynchronous?

```
(function() {
    var obj = {};
    function processMutation(mutation) {
        //do whatever with the mutation
        //update the obj variable
    }
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            //this really isn't IIFE since forEach already is an IIFE?
            setTimeout(function() {
                //pass it to a separate function and release the forEach function
                processMutation(mutation);
            }, 0);
            //this ^ should make it async?
        });
    });
    observer.observe(target, config);
})();
```

Doing it this way, will each mutation be added to the stack inside the `processMutation` function, making the processing of the mutations asynchronous and allowing the main thread to continue listening for other mutations?  Because some processing might require a long time to do...

Hope this question isn't too general...would like to get some advice.

Comment: Mutation events are already asynchronous. There's no point in further deferring them. `setTimeout` doesn't make your processing parallel.

Comment: @Bergi so my concerns about the mutations coming in rapidly...they will all get executed in the order which they came in?  Any the updates will be in order?

Comment: Yes, they will. The event loop guarantees that each event's (synchronous) processing will be finished before starting with the next.

Comment: @Bergi man...all that writing and thinking and it was for nothing :) Thanks for reassuring me!

Comment: Each mutation will invoke the callback function(the one that is the parameter of the MutationObserver constructor), and the callback function can access an array of `MutationRecords` for that particular mutation. When a series of mutations occur on target, a callback is invoked for each and since JavaScript is single threaded each invoked function executes one by one

Comment: @rps So new arrays of `MutationRecords` will get added on to the MutationObserver even if it is still processing the previous arrays, correct?

Comment: hmmm I don't get your question. Let's say on button click a div's background, font color & text size changes. Now, when the button is clicked the div would've have mutated and will invoke the mutationobserver callback function, the callback function will have the array of observed mutations(the kinds specified in the config) {1) background changed, 2) font color changed, 3) text size changed}

Comment: @rps yes, but a more complex example:what if a lot of html was changed at once and you have to parse that html and look for changes. And while you're parsing that html and looking for changes, another big mutation happens and the callback is called again. Does the new MutationRecord gets enqueued while the first record is processing? That's my question.

Comment: In that case won't each target be having its own mutationobserver observing it with its own mutationrecord array for when mutation happens ? Rather than a single mutationobserver handling all

Comment: @rps no, when the mutation happens, it's a childList mutation to an entire table. The whole table rows get added and they need to be parsed for changes. So it's one observer observing the table, not an observer for each row

Comment: Yup target will still be the table and not the rows. Let's say you've added "attributes" to the config of the mutationobserver, and an attribute of a row is changed, will that be observed? I don't think so. For monitoring rows they need their own mutationobserver